# What does the config file look like for System.ServiceMode.ClientBase<TChannel>(String)?

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-3.5, c#-3.0, web-config

I'm using a WCF service and want to use one of the constructors, but I don't see any documentation on what the config file should look like.

Am I missing the documentation, how else are we supposed to know?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms574925.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the link on that page in the remarks section where the text is [`<endpoint>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731762.aspx) will show you the endpoint configuration I believe you are looking for.   ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731762.aspx )